# How to find out which database the django project is connected to?

Tags: python, django, postgresql

My local django project has its database pointed to a local postgresql db `testdb`.

In the `settings.py`, my database connection is:

```
# Parse database configuration from $DATABASE_URL
import dj_database_url
DATABASES['default'] =  dj_database_url.config()
```

This was setup for deployment to Heroku later. 
However, I am suspecting the project is not connected to `testdb` at all. I tried to create a user in the admin panel, it is not showing up on my `auth_user` table. Also I keep getting errors with my newly created models. Despite having used `Migrate`

I have double checked $DATABASE_URL is `postgres:///testdb` and I have done `manage.py migrate` many times

Is there a way to tell which database my django project is connected to?

The local server I'm running is Gunicorn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem Solved.
There was a ghost session of Gunicorn running in the background, after killing the process and restart Gunicorn the problem is fixed